# How can I display the days of the week?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I am trying to list Sunday - Saturday of a current week.
Everything seems to work, but I never seem to get the dates I need.

**Example**

```
28 29 30 01 02 03 04 (I need)
28 29 07 08 02 03 04 (what I get)
```

**Code**

```
Sun <%= Date.today.beginning_of_week(:sunday).strftime('%b %d') %>

Mon <%= Date.today.beginning_of_week(:monday).strftime('%b %d') %>

Tue <%= Date.today.end_of_week(:wednesday).strftime('%b %d') %>

Wed <%= Date.today.end_of_week(:thursday).strftime('%b %d') %>

Thu <%= Date.today.end_of_week(:friday).strftime('%b %d') %>

Fri <%= Date.today.end_of_week(:saturday).strftime('%b %d') %>

Sat <%= Date.today.end_of_week.strftime('%b %d') %>
```

I have tried using both beginning_of_week and end_of_week but not luck. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a range and iterate through:

```
<% (Date.today.beginning_of_week(:sunday)...Date.today.end_of_week).each do |date| %>
  <p><%= date.strftime('%a %d') %></p>
<% end %>
```

Will give you:

```
<p>Sun 28</p>
<p>Mon 29</p>
<p>Tue 30</p>
<p>Wed 01</p>
<p>Thu 02</p>
<p>Fri 03</p>
<p>Sat 04</p>
```

Note that we're using `...` instead of `..` for the range.